# How to update DLL in approot/bin

Tags: iis, iis-7, azure

I currently have an Azure instance running. The problem is that Publishing to staging is taking 15+min each time.

I was hoping to make small changes to my code and update the corresponding DLL in the VM directly myself via remote desktop. However, when I try to copy paste the DLL into the approot/bin folder, I get an error that the file is currently in use.

I have already stopped the IIS instance in the IIS manager. What other service/process do I have to stop in order to update the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question after you RDP your instance, you can kill the role host process WaWebHost.exe or WaWorkerHost.exe which will release the DLL holdout and you can copy the DLL.

You have a very small window to copy your DLL to bin folder once you kill the host process so have it ready to copy. May be open a command window and write your command to copy DLL from Source to BIN, and then kill the host process (WaWebHost.exe/WaIISHost.exe/WaWorkerhost.exe) and then launch the command to copy DLL.

I also think you know that DLL will not persist so finally you would need to update package with proper dll as usual process.